# Distribution of random hyperplanes in projective spaces

Tags: pr.probability, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

Let $X\subset \mathbb{CP}^{N-1}$ be a smooth subvariety of dimension $n$. Assume that $X$ is not contained in a hyperplane of $\mathbb{CP}^{N-1}$.
Let $\mu$ be a smooth probability measure on $X$. Given general points $(x_1,\ldots,x_{N-1})\in X^{N-1}$, there is a unique hyperplane $H(x_1,\ldots,x_{N-1})$ passing through all these points.

My question is, **what is the expectation of the distribution of these hyperplanes**?

To be more precise, $H$ defines a rational map from $X^{N-1}$ to $\mathcal{D}'^{1,1}(\mathbb{CP}^{N-1})$ by integration, denote this map by $[H]$, then how to calculate the integral
$$
I=\int_{X^{N-1}} [H(x_1,\ldots,x_{N-1})]\,\mathrm{d}\mu^{\otimes  N-1}(x_1,\ldots,x_{N-1}).
$$

It is easy to see that the integral $I$ turns out to be a smooth form, so one could restrict it to $X$. Let $\nu$ be the push-forward measure of $\mu^{\otimes N-1}$ along $H$, hence $\nu$ is a probability measure on $\mathbb{CP}^{N-1\vee}$, then one finds that 
$$
I|_{X}=\int_{\mathbb{CP}^{N-1\vee}} [H\cap X]\,\mathrm{d}\nu(H).
$$
This expression is formally similar to the integral considered by [Shiffman-Zelditch](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9803052), the main difference being that $\nu$ is not the Fubini-Study measure. I do not know if one can get some information from this analogue.

Comment: If $X=\mathbb{CP}^{N-1}\subset \mathbb{CP}^N$ then  $N$ points on $X$ do not determine a unique hyperplane. Also if $X$ is a curve of degree $d<N$ you cannot $N$ points on $X$ contained in the same  hyperplane.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu Yes, you are right. I should modify the question a little bit to exclude these cases.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu I add the condition that $X$ is not contained in a hyperplane, so now everything seems OK.

Comment: Perhaps you should let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $\mathbb{CP}^N$ and study the expectation of $H(x_1,\dotsc, x_N)$.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu I think that the distribution of $H(x_1,\ldots)$ for $x_i\in \mathbb{P}^{N-1}$ with respect to a given measure on $\mathbb{P}^{N-1}$ is rather simple, the problem arises because we restrict attention to $X$ only.

Comment: I don't think it is simple. For example what happens if $\mu(U)=1$ where $U$ is a tiny open set so the points $x_i$ outside $U$ have probability $0$ of appearing in the average?

Comment: Also, the expectation need not be a $(n-1,n-1)$ form. It will be a closed form of degree $(2N-2)$.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu All integration happens within the locally convex space of (1,1)-currents, so the integral should still be of type $(1,1)$. I think what you mean is bidimension $(n-1,n-1)$ instead of bidegree.

Comment: No! $\mu$ is a real quantity and the result will be a closed form of degree $(2N-2)$. Its cohomology class  can indeed represented  by a form of bidegree $(N-1,N-1)$.